# When two intervals are disjoint, then outer measure is

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am self-studying real analysis by Sheldon Axler. This is a problem 7 from chapter 2A. He uses $|A|$ sign to indicate the outer measure of a set $A$.

Suppose $a, b, c, d$ are real numbers with $a<b$ and $c<d$. Prove that 
\begin{equation*}
|(a,b)\cup (c, d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)\text{ if and only if }(a,b)\cap (c, d)=\emptyset.
\end{equation*}

How do I prove if $(a, b)\cap(c, d)=\emptyset$ then $|(a,b)\cup (c, d)|=(b-a)+(d-c)$? I know $|(a,b)\cup (c, d)|\leq(b-a)+(d-c)$ but how do I get the equality? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and by disjointness assume with loss  of generalty that $b<c$

Then $(a,b) \cup (c,d) \supset [a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon] \cup [c+\epsilon,d-\epsilon]=:I_1 \cup I_2$

Not that $I_1,I_2$ are compact disjoint intervals so $d(I_1,I_2)=\inf\{|x-y|:x \in I_1,y \in I_2\}>0$

From this you have that $|I_1 \cup I_2|=|I_1|+|I_2|=(b-a)+(d-c)-4\epsilon$

So $|(a,b) \cup (c,d)| \geq (b-a)+(d-c)-4\epsilon$.

Sending $\epsilon \to 0$ gives you the conclusion.